# How set module view for custom searcher in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to integrate Fotolia Api with Prestashop 1.6.0.9.

I already make module with custom tab, but I have no idea how set view from module folder for this tab. Sorry to say, but "documentation for developers" SUCKS.
I can't find any working solution.

```
public function install() {
    if (!parent::install()
            || !$this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader')
            || !$this->registerHook('header')
    ) return false;

    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->class_name = 'AdminFotoliaSelector';
    $tab->id_parent = 0;
    $tab->module = $this->name;
    $tab->name[(int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))] = 'Fotolia Selector';
    $tab->add();

    return true;
}
```

I had big problem with make proper controller, and now I just can't load anything/ I have no idea how do this.

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;

class AdminFotoliaSelectorController extends ModuleAdminController {

public $name;

public function __construct() {
    $this->lang = (!isset($this->context->cookie) || !is_object($this->context->cookie)) ? intval(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) : intval($this->context->cookie->id_lang);
    parent::__construct();
}


public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->renderForm();
}

public function renderForm() {
    $path = _MODULE_DIR_."fotoliaselector";

    $more = $this->module->display($path, 'views/templates/admin/fotoliaselector.tpl');

    return $more.parent::renderForm();
}
```

When I try die($more) it gives me content of .tpl, anyway when I click tab in back office it's still empty.
I have debug options on, compiling on, cache off.

So just enlight me please, how am I supose to show ANYTHING there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't display tab's content at all.

I don't know what `module->display` method does, but I think you should change in `initContent()` method line:

```
$this->renderForm();
```

into

```
echo $this->renderForm();
```

If it won't help you should look at this [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Displaying+content+on+the+front-office) and try to do it without external classes - only try to use Smarty to display simple content without using `Tab` class or `AdminFotoliaSelector`

Comment: Hi, thanks four Your replay. Echo inject my code in some random place in header ruining all html structure. `module->display` return content of .tpl file. I'm trying to understand how this work but it's terrible for me, which hook should I use to attach on my custom created tab? Should I create new and load it in TPL, if yes how should I provide this TPL to module in proper way? Front end example it's okay, but for front office. I have problems with using in on back office. Pozdrawiam ;)   (greetings)

Comment: @amnestia Sorry but I cannot help you more with that. Maybe someone else who knows Prestashop will.

Answer (score 0):

Well i know it will sounds weird but you need to take some similar modules, and read his code and will see some methods names are the same in each module.

Then copy that, install and play with some changes etc.

Imho you miss standard method **getContent()** form where you need to pass some data for smarty:

```
public function getContent()
    {
          global $smarty, $cookie;
......
//some code 
......
          $this->_html .= '<script type="text/javascript"   src="'.__PS_BASE_URI__.'js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>';
          $this->_html .= '<h1>My module title or stuff</h1>';
          $this->_html .= $this->getMyCoolFormOrConfig();
          $smarty->assign('errors', $this->errors);
          $smarty->assign('message', $this->message);
          $this->_html .=  $this->display(__FILE__, 'name_of_tpl_file.tpl');
          return $this->_html;

     }
```

to simple add tab in BackOffice code like this:

```
        $id_tab=Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminPayment'); 
        $newtab=new Tab();
        $newtab->id_parent=$id_tab;
        $newtab->module=$this->name;
        $newtab->class_name='MyClassName'; //will be same like MyClassName.php in folder of you module where you need to create you class and extend the AdminTab and from there with function you need to echo you name module
        $newtab->position=Tab::getNbTabs($id_tab)+1;
        $newtab->name[$cookie->id_lang]=$this->l("Name of you stuff");
        $newtab->name[Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')]=$this->l("Name of you stuff");
        $newtab->add();
```

Study this file there **/controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php**
and you see what methods are using in each module

Take a look greater feature to generate you module structure (register requeired) https://validator.prestashop.com/generator